# ¿Se puede simplificar este código?, array dentro de otro array

Tags: javascript, array

¿Alguien puede decirme si voy bién?, el codigo funciona, pero ¿Se puede simplificar lo que estoy haciendo?, creo que estoy repitiendo varias cosas.

Quiero validar un formulario con puros radio button, comparar cada respuesta y mostrar un mensaje de acuerdo a lo que el usuario acaba de seleccionar

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var click=['#fila1 input:checked','#fila2 input:checked','#fila3 input:checked','#fila4 input:checked','#fila5 input:checked'];
var array= new Array(5);

array[0] = new Array(3);
array[1] = new Array(7);
array[2] = new Array(2);
array[3] = new Array(2);
array[4] = new Array(2);
```

Comment: Hola Anselmo, si tu codigo funciona... podrias colocar el html de tu formulario para ver como funciona, un poco complejo leer tu codigo y de poder simplificar se puede partiendo por la definicion de array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías remplazar la cadena de **OR** por algo así:   `array[1].indexOf(jQuery(click[1]).val()) != -1`

Answer (score -1):

La primera simplificación de código que se me ocurre es que inicialices los array con un array con valores definidos y no a cada posición darle un valor, tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
array[0] = ['Iluminación','Ventilación','Acceso'];
array[1] = ['Baño','Estancia','Descanso','Sala','Cocina','Habitación','Lavandería'];
array[2] = ['Mayor el ancho que el alto','Mayor el alto que el ancho'];
array[3] = ['Si','No'];
array[4] = ['Si','No'];
```

De todas formas se puede simplificar aun mas, lo dejo acá abajo, quizás sea un poco mas ilegible, pero  útil saberlo...

```
var array = [['Iluminación','Ventilación','Acceso'],
['Baño','Estancia','Descanso','Sala','Cocina','Habitación','Lavandería'],
['Mayor el ancho que el alto','Mayor el alto que el ancho'],
['Si','No'],['Si','No']];
```

Luego si subis mas codigo, prodiamos ver de reducir aun mas.